# cannot connect mongodb with ssh when ran as service

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssh

I am running mongodb on AWS.

When I do `sudo service mongod start` mongo runs at port `27017` and the data communication between the app and the db works flawlessly. However, I cannot connect to it with MongoDB Compass SSH connection. It says `Error creating SSH Tunnel: (SSH) Channel open failure: Connection refused`.

When I check `netstat` port `27017` is being listened fine. Also I cannot launch another instance of mongo because the port is already being listened.

Funny thing is that if I stop the serivce by going `sudo service mongod stop` and if I don't run it as a service but just run it on the terminal by going `sudo mongod`, I can connect via `SSH` just fine. Why is this?

Comment: Have a look at https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/